# Save Edits disabled when editing a question during a first post review

Tags: support, review, edits

I'm reviewing a first post (question) and saw that the question was poorly spelled and formatted so I attempted an edit. I edited the the title, the post and the tags, and filled the edit summary. I then noticed that "Save Edit" is disabled.

What is the reason for the disabled link? Is this a matter of insufficient rep? I don't have the edit privilege yet, but I was able to go into edit mode. Maybe some required field was missing? I'm not sure, but I think that some tooltip on the disabled "save Edit" link would help figuring out what's wrong.

EDIT:

When I access the question directly (not through review), and click edit, the Save Edit link is enabled.

Here are some screenshots:

Save Edits disabled on review:
[image: Save Edits disabled on review]

Save Edits enabled on direct link to question:
[image: Save Edits enabled on question page]

Comment: I guess the behaviour of the GUI has changed a little since this question was asked : today I was reviewing a First Post and started editing it, but I _could_ click the "Save Edits" button (it wasn't disabled). But then I got the message "This would have to be a Suggested Edit". So apparently when you don't have sufficient rep for a direct edit, you cannot suggest edits when reviewing a post. But there's no way to know until AFTER carefully crafting your edit, which is a pain.